# Serial Programming and I2C port "conflict"

Tags: i2c, attiny, isp, attiny85

I'm designing a board in which an [Attiny85](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf) is connected to an accelerometer ([MPU-6050](https://www.cdiweb.com/datasheets/invensense/MPU-6050_DataSheet_V3%204.pdf)) via I2C.

The I2C pins are in the ISP bus (SDA/MOSI, SCL/SCK). I wonder what happens to the accelerometer during programming of the MCU?

Are there any best practices I should follow? I considered just adding some solder jumpers, but I wonder if any precaution is even necessary.

[image]

[image]

Edit:

After finding out this is problematic, I'll try a solution based on [Bruce Abbotts answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/258310/61257) in another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MPU-6050` may prevent you from programming the ATTiny successfully. It would interpret the ISP data as I²C and react accordingly. Expect *interesting* behaviuor on *both* SCL and SDA lines.

During programming the SCL and SDA should be disconnected from the Tiny MCU, e.g. by jumpers or dip switches.

Comment: Hmm, since during programming RST is pulled low, do you think it would be enough to just turn off the MPU? (i.e. with a couple FETs and RC filters to filter the pulse after chip erase)

Comment: RST is not wired up to the MPU in any way. And check the datasheet on the allowed voltages on SDA/SCL lines with respect to VCC in case you just wanted to cut the power.

Comment: I meant using RST to control FETs cutting power to the MPU. But thats another question altogether. I might just use a pin in the Tiny to do that instead.

Comment: Datasheet chapter 6.9 disallows that. Input voltages on SDA,SCL must not be bigger than VCC + 0.5 V. That includes the case when VCC= 0V aka powered off. In practise you will reverse power the chip, giving you even *more interesting* behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking that up. I guess I'll have to find another method.